# cocos2d, how to make b2World draw my own data?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, draw, box2d

I am working on a Box2d Editor for iOS, using cocos2d.

I wrapped `b2World` into my own World class. I want to implement my own draw functionality. Since I will be drawing higher level classes (Wall, Rope, etc) it is not enough to create a `b2Draw` subclass and set it as DebugDraw of the world, but I also need to change the `b2World` `DrawDebugData`.

Is it a good idea to inherit my World class from `CCLayer` and override the `draw` method? Whats a better approach?

Comment: I think you said the answer yourself - 'I need to change the b2World DrawDebugData'. Or for a more forward thinking solution, you could have the wall, rope draw themselves by giving them references to the Box2D bodies they are made of.

Comment: First approach, change DrawDebugData: do you mean, directly change b2World.cpp? I dont think thats a good approach. Also I think b2World is not prepared to be extended. Second approach: model objects may draw themselves but still someone has to invoke that draw method, so we are still in approach 1.

Comment: I don't understand.  All you want is to control debug drawing?  All you need to do to do that is write your own code in -(void)draw.

Comment: True, directly changing b2World is probably only appropriate if you're just tweaking a line or two, but don't rule it out if that would save you a lot of trouble implementing other workarounds. Second approach: I meant you would invoke drawing of the objects yourself - but I don't know much about cocos so I may be out of my depth there :)

Comment: @Aaron -(void) draw from which class do you mean?

Comment: Draw is a method of CCNode (I think) so is in any CCNode subclass (or maybe it's CCLayer?).  Any OpenGL drawing you do you generally do inside of the draw method.  It is called every step I believe.  I don't manually do much OpenGL stuff.

Comment: I have used it in the past though to draw CGRects when I want to actually see my test rects (checking to see if the rect contains a point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer I would like people to read.**

Even if the b2World implements some drawing functionality, it is just meant for debugging purposes and should be used as it is (unless you want to change one or two lines).

If you want to draw your higher level objects (or to change debug draw's behaviour) you are not supposed to modify b2World's draw or the GLES-Render. Instead, you override CCSprite / CCLayer drawing methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just add CCSprite pointer into `b2Body` userData  to attach a sprite to b2Body. Then every frame update your sprites position according to position of b2bodies.

Comment: that's not what I want. I need to deal with OpenGL directives, to draw shapes just like box2d's debug draw does, but extending that functionality for example to change the color when objects are in certain state.

Comment: @Ave: reiplement draw() function of CCSprite and draw what you like

Comment: Ya, I think I am getting to the point. There is no way to extend the debugDraw stuff. One has to either choose whether to use it as it is, or to implement the entire draw stuff from scratch.